# SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook (Spark and Kubernetes)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to run spark and ml-lib code in a kubernetes cluster.
When I ran the same code in client mode or inside a docker which I build it is working with out any issue.
But when I ran the same code inside kubernetes cluster (PKS platform) its failing with no error.

```py
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf
    from pyspark.sql.functions import percent_rank
    from pyspark.sql import Window
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
    from pyspark.ml.regression import GBTRegressor
    from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
    from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
    from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler,VectorIndexer
    from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast   
    import datetime
    ##########sparkcontext###############
    sc= SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    print("started")
    ###########RMSLE-calusulation########
    def rmsle(real, predicted):
       sum=0.0
        for x in range(len(predicted)):
        if predicted[x]<0 or real[x]<0: #check for negative values
            continue
        p = np.log(predicted[x]+1)
        r = np.log(real[x]+1)
        sum = sum + (p - r)**2
        return (sum/len(predicted))**0.5
    ##########Reading of imput Data###########
    customer = sqlContext.read.csv('hdfs://XXXXXX:/user/root/customer.csv', header=True, inferSchema = True)
    customer =customer.select("*").toPandas()
    lineitem = sqlContext.read.csv('hdfs://XXXXXXX:/user/root/lineitem.csv', header=True, inferSchema = True)
    lineitem =lineitem.select("*").toPandas()
    order = sqlContext.read.csv('hdfs://XXXXXXX:/user/root/orders.csv', header=True, inferSchema = True)
    order =order.select("*").toPandas()
    print("data has been read")
    ###########ETL############################
    sales = order.join(customer, order.o_custkey == customer.c_custkey, how = 'inner')
    sales = sales.sort_index()
    sales.columns = ['key_old', 'o_orderdate', 'o_orderkey', 'o_custkey', 'o_orderpriority',
       'o_shippriority', 'o_clerk', 'o_orderstatus', 'o_totalprice',
       'o_comment', 'c_custkey', 'c_mktsegment', 'c_nationkey', 'c_name',
       'c_address', 'c_phone', 'c_acctbal', 'c_comment']
    sales2 = sales.join(lineitem,sales.o_orderkey == lineitem.l_orderkey, how = 'outer')
    sales3 = sales2.groupby(by = 'o_orderdate')
    sales4 = sales3.agg({'l_quantity': 'sum'})# .withColumnRenamed("sum(l_quantity)", "TOTAL_SALES") .withColumnRenamed("o_orderdate", "ORDERDATE")
    print("End of ETL pipeline")
    orderdates = pd.to_datetime(sales4.index.values)
    orderdates = [datetime.datetime(i.year, i.month, i.day,) for i in orderdates]
    l = []
    l2 = []
    for i in orderdates:
        l = []
        l.append(i.timestamp())
        l.append(i.day)
        l.append(i.timetuple().tm_wday)
        l.append(i.timetuple().tm_yday)
        l.append(i.isocalendar()[1])
        l2.append(l)
    print("dateconverted")
    tmp = np.array(sales4.values)
    tmp = tmp.reshape(tmp.shape[0],)
    data_new = pd.DataFrame()
    data_new['SALES'] = tmp
    data_new[['DATE','DAY','WDAY','YDAY','WEEK']] = pd.DataFrame(np.array(l2))
    data_new['ONES'] = np.ones((len(data_new)))
    print("converted to datframe")
    X = np.array(data_new[['DATE','DAY','WDAY','YDAY','WEEK','ONES']])
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1])
    Y = np.array(data_new[['SALES']])
    Y = Y.reshape(Y.shape[0],1)
    cutoff = 0.1
    length = int((1-cutoff)*(len(X)))
    X_train = X[0:length]
    X_test = X[length:len(X)]
    Y_train = Y[0:length]
    Y_test = Y[length:len(Y)]
    print("pre-processingdone")
    weights  = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X_train.T,X_train)),X_train.T),Y_train)
    print("model Ready")
    Y_pred = np.dot(X_test,weights)
    Y_pred = Y_pred.reshape(Y_pred.shape[0],)
    Y_test = Y_test.reshape(Y_test.shape[0],)
    print("predictions done")
    RMSE = np.sqrt(np.mean((Y_test-Y_pred)**2))
    RMSLE = rmsle(Y_test,Y_pred)
    print(RMSE)
    print(RMSLE
    sc.stop()
```

Environment

Kubernetes cluster : PKS platform

Having enough memory 16GB with master and 16GB RAM with worker nodes of 3

I don't see any spike and during processing it hardly utilising 30% of memory from cluster.

My image is 2GB and data is hardly 100MB.

Its failing during below code:

```py
    weights  = np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X_train.T,X_train)),X_train.T),Y_train)
    print("model Ready")
    Y_pred = np.dot(X_test,weights)
    Y_pred = Y_pred.reshape(Y_pred.shape[0],)
    Y_test = Y_test.reshape(Y_test.shape[0],)
    print("predictions done")
    RMSE = np.sqrt(np.mean((Y_test-Y_pred)**2))
    RMSLE = rmsle(Y_test,Y_pred)
    print(RMSE)
    print(RMSLE)
    sc.stop()
```

Below is part of driver log and I don't see any error in log

```
19/12/26 10:52:23 INFO Context Cleaner: Cleaned accumulator 238
19/12/26 10:52:23 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 222
19/12/26 10:52:23 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 241
19/12/26 10:52:23 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 228

data has been read
End of ETL pipeline
dateconverted
converted to datframe

pre-processingdone
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://spark-ml-test-4ff4386f41d48a9f-driver-svc.spark-jobs.svc:4040
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
19/12/26 10:52:35 WARN ExecutorPodsWatchSnapshotSource: Kubernetes client has been closed (this is expected if the application is shutting down.)
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-18e6167c-433f-41d8-82c4-b11ba9a3bf8c/spark-3a8d3e48-292c-4018-b003-bde80641eb90/pyspark-4b10b351-cf07-4452-8285-acb67157db80
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-29b813d2-f377-4d84-be3a-4372f69e58b5
19/12/26 10:52:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-18e6167c-433f-41d8-82c4-b11ba9a3bf8c/spark-3a8d3e48-292c-4018-b003-bde80641eb90
```

Any guess or idea on this

Comment: Did you try running a simpler code to narrow down the issue ? Loading the whole big chunk all at once is kind of audacious. Did you try to run the code excluding the part after the weights computation and see if it fires the same shutdown ?

Comment: @Mehdi LAMRANI  : Yes I have ran parts of code and workign succesfully before weights. its stopping execution from weights and thrwoing no error execpt SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook  , so not getting any idea how to proceed